# Kotlin: Async tasks inside foreach loop

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to call tasks asynchronously, so it can varied how long will each task take, but I want to wait for all of them to be finished in order to continue in next line under for loop. How can I achieve that? Because so far its not happening. Code below `foreach` should be called only if all of those tasks are finished. I'm looking for some "elegant" way to solve this, I dont wanna use some while loop and freeze entire thread.

Code:

```
    val failedTasks = mutableListOf<ApiTask<T>>()
    App.log("apiCallChained: startCall")
    apiBlocks.forEachIndexed { i, apiBlock->
        App.log("apiCallChained: callingTask: $i")
        launch(Dispatchers.Main){
            val (r, err) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                try {
                    apiBlock.apiBlock(this) to null
                } catch (e: ApiCallError) {
                    null to e
                }
            }

            when {
                r != null -> {
                    App.log("apiCallChained: callingTask: $i - success")
                    apiBlock.onSuccess(r)
                }
                err != null -> {
                    App.log("apiCallChained: callingTask: $i - error")
                    failedTasks.add(apiBlock)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    App.log("apiCallChained: endCall: ${failedTasks.size}")
    if (failedTasks.isEmpty()) onSuccess.invoke() else onError.invoke(failedTasks)
```

Logs:

```
apiCallChained: startCall
apiCallChained: callingTask: 0
apiCallChained: callingTask: 1
apiCallChained: callingTask: 2
apiCallChained: callingTask: 3
apiCallChained: callingTask: 4
apiCallChained: endCall: 0
apiCallChained: callingTask: 2 - success
apiCallChained: callingTask: 3 - success
apiCallChained: callingTask: 4 - success
apiCallChained: callingTask: 0 - success
apiCallChained: callingTask: 1 - success
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way two ways to do this without freezing the thread is with a callback or by directly running all of it in a coroutine to begin with.

So either:

```
scope.launch {
    //replacement for your code above, see below...

    // code to call after work finished...
}
```

or, assuming your CoroutineScope defaults to the main thread and you want to react on the main thread, you can call a callback from inside your coroutine. It looks like you already are doing something like this with your `onSuccess` and `onError` callbacks.

```
// This could be a ()->Unit callback passed into the function that runs this code:
val onWorkFinished = {
    // code to call after work finished...
}

scope.launch {
    //replacement for your code above, see below...

    onWorkFinished()
}
```

So, the code we are replacing your above code with is in a coroutine. The typical way to do a bunch of parallel work and wait for all of it is by using a `coroutineScope` block. The block suspends until all children coroutines finish. You can replace your above code with:

```
val failedTasks = mutableListOf<ApiTask<T>>()
App.log("apiCallChained: startCall")
coroutineScope {
    apiBlocks.forEachIndexed { i, apiBlock->
        launch(Dispatchers.Main){
            val (r, err) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                try {
                    apiBlock.apiBlock(this) to null
                } catch (e: ApiCallError) {
                    null to e
                }
            }

            when {
                r != null -> {
                    App.log("apiCallChained: callingTask: $i - success")
                    apiBlock.onSuccess(r)
                }
                err != null -> {
                    App.log("apiCallChained: callingTask: $i - error")
                    failedTasks.add(apiBlock)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
App.log("apiCallChained: endCall: ${failedTasks.size}")
if (failedTasks.isEmpty()) onSuccess.invoke() else onError.invoke(failedTasks)
```

Incidentally, you can simplify it as follows:

```
val failedTasks = mutableListOf<ApiTask<T>>()
App.log("apiCallChained: startCall")
coroutineScope {
    apiBlocks.forEachIndexed { i, apiBlock->
        launch(Dispatchers.Main){
            try {
                 val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { apiBlock.apiBlock(this) }
                 App.log("apiCallChained: callingTask: $i - success")
                 apiBlock.onSuccess(result)
            } catch (e: ApiCallError) {
                 App.log("apiCallChained: callingTask: $i - error")
                 failedTasks.add(apiBlock)
            }
        }
    }
}
App.log("apiCallChained: endCall: ${failedTasks.size}")
if (failedTasks.isEmpty()) onSuccess.invoke() else onError.invoke(failedTasks)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async to run a task asynchronously and wait for the result. The `async {}` method returns a Deferred result that you can use to wait for at a later point, there are also convenienve methods for waiting on a list of Deferred.

eg:

```
suspend myFun(apiBlocks: list<ApiTask<T>>) = coroutineScope {
    App.log("apiCallChained: startCall")
    val deferredResults = mutableListOf<Deferred<String>>()
    apiBlocks.forEachIndexed { i, apiBlock->
        deferredResults.add(
            async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {
                    apiBlock.apiBlock(this) to null
                } catch (e: ApiCallError) {
                    null to e
                }
            }
        )
    }
    val results = deferredResults.awaitAll()
    //now you can check 'results' for the jobs that succeeded/failed etc
    for((r, err) in results) {
        when {
            r != null -> {
                App.log("apiCallChained: callingTask: $i - success")
                //....
            }
            err != null -> {
                App.log("apiCallChained: callingTask: $i - error")
                //....
            }
        }
    }
}
```